# The possible for bucket sort combine with merge sort

Tags: algorithm, bucket-sort

Here is the thing. I was doing leetcode 164 Maximum Gap. 
The optimal solution for that one is bucket sort.

That makes me think a little bit more about sorting problem. 
Let say we have a list as follow:

2 ,5 ,19, 444, -14, 89, 16, 77

for what I think, we can arrange these number by two different range, (min, mid) (mid, max)
and mid should be min + (max - min) / 2;

Therefore we got (-14, 215) (216, 444)

we set min to leftmost and max to the rightmost, and fill other element based on the range, 
then we got

-14 2, 5, 19, 89, 16, 77
444

we recall the sort for two range, and for left one, we have 
(-14, 37) (38, 89) and the list

-14 2, 5, 19, 16

77 89

recursion that, then we gonna have sorted list;

I tired to write that one, it does work. The run time is O(n log(n)) and space complexity is O(n)
To be honest, I'm still a student, and not really good at algorithm. So I really cannot make it better.
I just want to ask, it there any possible that this one can be much faster than n logn.
I mean the worst case, not the special situation.

Comment: Bucket sort is O(n); that's why it's preferable when applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, non-comparison based sorting can break the glass floor of O(nlogn).
Bucket sort is in O(N), but it requires knowing in advance the
numbers are well-distributed over an interval (i, j). Radix sort is often stated in O(N), but it also depends on the length of those digits. For your problem, if you already know the interval of the distribution, you can try bucket sort or radix sort.